# ajax form send notification jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, pnotify

I ve got a form which I am sending via jquery ajax. What I am trying to achieve is:
Before the form is sent there should be a notification 'sending' and after the request is done, this message should disappear and there should be a message "sent". I am using pnotify.
What I tried so far is:

```
inProcess = function(){
            m = $.pnotify({
                title: "sending"
            });
            return true;
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax('',{
            method: "POST",
            data: myform.serialize,

            beforeSend: inProcess,

            complete: function(response){
                $.pnotify({
                    title: "Sent",
                    type: "success",
                    opacity: "0.8",
                    delay: 5000
                });
                m.remove();
            }
        });
```

This one does not work:

1. For any reason the 'sent' is appearing *before* sending. Why?
2. The remove() function removes the notification before it is created, But it is not removed completely, one can see that the 'sending' notification is shifted down. How can I remove the notification completely?
3. Do I really need to wrap the 'sending' call inside a function, only because `beforeSend` requires a `true` as return code? Or is there a more elegant way? Especially I do not like the global `m` variable

**Edit**:

According to some comments and some google' ing, I changed my code to:

```
inProcess = function(){
            m = $.pnotify({
                title: "sending"
            });
            return true;
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax('',{
            method: "POST",
            data: myform.serialize,

            beforeSend: inProcess,

            complete: setTimeout(function(response){
                $.pnotify({
                    title: "Sent",
                    type: "success",
                    opacity: "0.8",
                    delay: 5000
                });
                $.pnotify_remove_all(),1000)
            }
        });
```

Which seems to work but is not really satisfactory due to the questions above

Comment: Thanks. I guess you mean `complete: setTimeout(function(response){...}` . I' d rather not do this, because in this case, the complete function is always called with a delay, regardless whether the request was fast or not. I think it is a rather hacky solution

Answer (score 0):

the following way is easier 4 me.
could help:

```
inProcess();

$.post(
'file.php',
{
  data: myform.serialize
},
function(response)
{
  success(response);
  $.pnotify({
   title: "Sent",
   type: "success",
   opacity: "0.8",
   delay: 5000
  });
},'json'
)
.always(function() { m.remove(); }
);
```

Comment: In this case inProcess is called even before the form is sent... I just want it to appear on the sending event

Comment: you could include these lines:

.ajaxStart(function() {
 inProcess();
});
.ajaxStop(function() {
 m.remove();
});
.ajaxError(function() {
 alert('error');
});